# I have tried using styled component in my App. But the cursor moves out after I write city name

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In the search area every time I type any letter the cursor moves out and I need to click the text area again to type the next letter. While using CSS it is working fine but in Styled components I am facing the issue. I think there is some issues with my styling but I am unable to debug.  How can I fix this issue. Please help.

```
import React, { FC, useState, FormEvent } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { setAlert } from '../store/actions/alertActions';
import { getWeather, setLoading } from '../store/actions/weatherActions';

interface SearchProps {
  title: string;
}


const Search: FC<SearchProps> = ({ title }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');

  const changeHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCity(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(city.trim() === '') {
      return dispatch(setAlert('City is required!'));
    }

    dispatch(setLoading());
    dispatch(getWeather(city));
    setCity('');
  }
   
  const Header = styled.h1`
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family:  'sans-serif';
    padding-top: 30px;
  `;

  const Input = styled.input`
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #b4e6df;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    ::placeholder {
      color: black;
      
    }
  `;

  const Button = styled.button`
    background-color: #10e2f1;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 3px;
    padding: 0.25em 6em;
    
  `;
  return(
    <>
          <Header >{title}
          <form  onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <Input 
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter city name"
              value={city}
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
            <br/>
            <Button >Search</Button>
          </form>
          </Header>
    </>
  );  
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: First I would add a throttling functionality. Which means you don't fire a new api-request as long as the user is typing. On the other hand, I don't see your search-input. Make sure, that it will not re-renderd if your request-results updated.

Comment: Where are you trying to type? I can't see any input element code in the above code.

Comment: @Mr_Green I have fixed the code now. Sorry I copied wrong code earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value is changing (or refreshing) whenever you make a change in the input as it is bind with state and also the state is updating on `onChange` event. Keep independent value instead of state variable in `value` attribute. something like this:

```
const defaultValue = ''; // or the default value you are getting from props
const [city, setCity] = useState(defaultValue);

---
---
<Input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter city name"
    value={defaultValue}
    onChange={changeHandler}
/>
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @YajnaseniPanda check my update. Let me know

Comment: I tried that but faced same issue. However when I tried to set  const changeHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCity(e.currentTarget.defaultValue);
    
  }     then I can type whole city but it still shows City is required

Comment: now my code works actually I had put all the styling inside of  Search function and the styling was local. Now I defined them global so it is working. Thank you :)